# WD Elements portable hard drive does not work with Gateway MX6454 laptop running x86 Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a Gateway MX6454 laptop purchased in 2006. It is running Windows 7 Ultimate x86. I purchased a WD Elements external hard drive model wdbuzg5000abk. It is supposed to be compatible with USB 2.0. When I plug it into the computer, the computer does not recognize it.

I have another computer also running windows 7 an the drive works on that computer. Using the device manager, I see it uses following two files for the drivers:
c:\windows\system32\disk.sys
c:\windows\system32\partmgr.sys

These files are present on my gateway MX6454. also this page http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/search/1/a_id/1708/c/130/p/228,219,290 is saying no additional drivers are needed.

how can I make the drive work?

Comment: Same USb cable on both computers? Do the USB ports on the problem computer work for any other storage devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try the drive in all of the USB ports, and make sure the laptop is plugged in when you do - particularly if it's only using a standard single-connector USB cable. On a laptop of that age, it's possible that the drive's power requirements are at or slightly beyond the maximum power that the USB ports are able to provide, particularly if it's in a lower-power mode due to running on battery.

edit: Searching the Amazon reviews for the drive gives conflicting information on its power requirements - at least one person states that it requires 750ma where standard USB 2.0 provides only 500ma, but other reviewers have had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have a local problem with the USB ports/drivers/software on your laptop.
If you see the drive correctly on another system, means it is functional.
You could check admininstrative tools-->disk management to see if the drive has an assigned letter.

What do you mean by "does not recognize it" ?
Does it say 'usb device not recognized' or nothing happens ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's USB2.0 at least you should be golden (however, even USB1.1 will work - I know firsthand).
If the drive doesn't work there may be several issues:

1. USB port is damaged and does not provide sufficient power to the drive. Try on another port.
2. If the drive does not work on any port uncheck "Selective USB suspend" option (that is: turn it off)
3. If that doesn't help you're out of luck. Only way now is to invest in the USB hub with external power (and that at least 2A).
4. If that doesn't help there is something wrong with the system. Leave it be.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers are not the issue here. They are integrated in Windows and you shouldn't need to install anything additional to get it to work.
The problem is that your laptop has USB 2.0 ports and often USB 2.0 port on older devices cannot supply enough power to the HDD. You can get a Y USB cable and connect the HDD using it. This way the HDD should get enough power.
Other possible reasons are a USB port gone faulty, USB cable too long/ gone faulty.